# How do I add a gui to an already written code?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, netbeans

I am currently working on my Computer Science Internal Assessment and am doing Object-Oriented Programming using java in Netbeans.

I have written the code and the output works as i want it to but I was wondering if there was an easy way to switch from using the output terminal to using a GUI for the user interface.

Comment: In Java, you can create windows with buttons/text-boxes etc. using the Swing libraries (they are part of the main Java library). Maybe have a look at the examples at https://javatutorial.net/jframe-buttons-listeners-text-fields (or search the web for others..=

Comment: Not really. GUI is event-driven. You are supposed to write different parts of the program as responses to user input, where in a console program you'd be prompting for input. You could start a dialog box for each prompt but that's not proper GUI. So you'll need change your program in non-trivial ways.

Comment: You could use Swing in your class or you could use JavaFX and transfer your Code from your main() to start(). JavaFX is state of the art. Don't waste to much time with Swing.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to a GUI programming tutorial.

The native GUI of Java is called "Swing" but there are other alternative available.

As an alternative, you may deploy your application on a Java Application server (e.g. "Apache Tomcat") and provide a HTML based web GUI. If you want to go this way, then search for a "Java Servlet" tutorial.

You will then possibly go one step further and use a template engine (like "Freemarker" or "Java Server Faces") instead of producing HTML text by string concatenation.

Now you have the right keywords to google for.

In either case you should know that GUI applications are driven by events. Instead of having loops that ask the user for input, the users clicks on buttons or enters text which is sent to your application by an event handling system. So that means, you will possibly need to rewrite major parts of your program. This will be covered by the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand your question but if you're using netbeans then make a GUI with it! They have a drag and drop interface which is easy to use.

You can make a JTextField for each of your inputs for the program and reference the value in the text field like so...

```
String value = textField.getText();
```

If you've never made a netbeans GUI before you can probably find a simple youtube video to get you started.

Goodluck ;)